# Run a jenkins job without triggering its downstream jobs

Tags: jenkins, triggers, dependencies, jobs

I have a jenkins job named "a", that triggers job "b" after it finishes successfully (job "b" is on the *down-stream* of job "a")

Is there a way to run job "a" without automatically triggering job "b"?
Maybe some kind of plugin ?

Comment: Can you provide some more info for your situation? How do you trigger job "b"? In which cases do you want to trigger job "b" when job "a" run? And in which case not?

Answer (score 0):

**Disable** job "b". Then it won't run even when it's getting triggered from "a".

If you need a more dynamic/automated solution, then you can also disable/enable job "b" from within job "a".

Answer (score 0):

If you check your configuration on the UPSTREAM job, you must have added a **POST-BUILD** step, just as shown below and there would be a possible selection out of what is displayed here. The Job B that you talk about, it will be triggered based on the outcome of Job A and by the choices that are available, it will be triggered irrespective of the choice that you make from the drop-down.

[image]

Hence the only option left out is to **DISABLE** it, on scenarios (the outcomes of Job A) that you think where Job B should not be triggered.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Post-build action in job "a" that is of a type "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" will trigger project "b" automatically. Replace the post-build action with type "Build other projects (manual step)".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32785844)

Answer (score 0):

You can run a jenkins job without triggering the downstream job by adding a *choice* parameter:

[image]

Next, in the prebuild steps you want to add an execute shell with a simple conditional statement:
[image]

```
if [ "${FortifyScan_To_Trigger}"  == "true" ]; then
touch runfortify.txt else
echo " No scan" fi
```

In the post steps, add a conditional step as below:
[image]

Add steps to the condition that will trigger the downstream job:
[image]

[image]

Next, you want to build your job. If the condition in the shell is `true`, it checks for the `runfortify` file then triggers downstream job when the main job is complete. But, if the condition is `false` it only runs the main job and the downstream job will not run. Hope this helps.